# Status is over 140 characters

Tags: twitterizer

I'm looking at using Twitterizer in my app. I've got it working, however, if a post is made with a URL taking it over 140 characters, twitter does not auto shorten the url with t.co.

Basically, I'm limiting user text entry to 125 characters and then adding the url. This, however, takes it over the 140 character mark. I noticed that LinqToTwitter has a wrapLinks parameter on their UpdateStatus method, with the following description "Shorten URLs with t.co wrapper." is there something similar with Twitterizer?

I was hoping that I could limit user entry to 120 characters to take into account the 20 character url by t.co. And add the url to the end of the post, as there will always be a url in the status update.

[Update]
This is the basic question

When using Twitterizer is there anyway to get Twitter to automatically shorten the url that is in the tweet. Thus enabling me to send a tweet that is over 140 characters. So the tweet would be made up of the following 120 characters being the tweet characters 121+ would be the url

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: When using Twitterizer is there anyway to get Twitter to automatically shorten the url that is in the tweet. Thus enabling me to send a tweet that is over 140 characters. So the tweet would be made up of the following

120 characters being the tweet

characters 121+ would be the url

Comment: Please edit this into your question.

Comment: I've now added this into the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the impression that Twitter's link shortening would be all on, or all off. Looking into this question I now see that currently there is a parameter that instructs Twitter to shorten links. Twitterizer doesn't currently have this parameter, but I will add it shortly.

Eventually, Twitter will make shortening links the default behavior.

Comment: must admit that was what I thought.

Comment: I was going to try to look into the source code but could not figure out how to get it. Mainly use GitHub

Comment: @Tanzy The source code for Twitterizer is no longer on GitHub, at least not officially. I had a git hub mirror for a while, but the script to keep it up to date stopped working.

Comment: Code changes for support has been committed, you can see the code diff here: http://pm.twitterizer.net/projects/twitterizer/repository/revisions/515

Comment: That's great thanks, how do I get the source? Or is a new NuGet package going to be released soon. I tend to use NuGet, but like copies of source to help me learn new things :)